# Obj-c: Custom Object handling

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am creating my own custom object, and I am wondering if I need to retain my properties or use something else such as copy (which does what?)?

```
@interface Asset : NSObject {
    NSString *name;
    NSNumber *assetId;
    NSNumber *linkId;
    NSNumber *parentId;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name; // should I use retain here or something else?
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *assetId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *linkId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *parentId;

@end
```

Also, in my .m, do I also need synthesize as well as release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My personal preference:

```
@interface Asset : NSObject {
    // no need to declare them here the @synthesize in the .m will sort all that out
}


// use copy for NSString as it is free for NSString instances and protects against NSMutableString instances being passed in...thanks to @bbum for this
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;

// no need for copy as NSNumber is immutable
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSNumber *assetId;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSNumber linkId;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSNumber parentId;

@end
```

Comment: You should use `copy`;   it is free for `NSString` and defense against someone passing in a mutable string.

Comment: ah.. well that's something I've learnt today...is it also free on NSNumbers?

Comment: probably; `copy` is generally free on non-mutable objects (including things like NSArray).

Answer (score 4):

The chapter on [Declared Properties](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html) in *The Objective-C Programming Language* explains what `copy` does and about synthesizing accessors.

Answer (score 1):

For typical cases your .m will have lines like this:

```
@synthesize name;
...
```

That tells the compiler to automatically emit the getter/setter methods.  You can also write/override these yourself.
So, when someone does a fooAsset.name = x, your object will retain its own reference to 'x'.
The other thing you need is a dealloc method to release the references to your members:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [name release];
    ....
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Note that it'll still be appropriate if 'name' is never assigned; nil will silently eat the 'release' message.